# rtmp vod, how to play multiple video files(mp4 or flv) continuously using simplertmp client

Tags: rtmp, wowza, playlist

as the title shows, is there any methods I can use to play multiple videos continuously using simple rtmp client(my rtmp server is wowza)? Here is the way I think:

when the first video is about to be finished，open a new thread to send a new createStream command and a new play command and get the video rtmp packet and put them into a buffer list, when the first video is finished, then play the video rtmp in the buffer list..

Can this way be available or are there any other recommended methods to achieve it? Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking into implementing a playlist of VOD files?

Comment: hi, thanks for your replying, you mean a server-side playlist or a client-side list? What I know is that the wowza does not support vod playlist yet, or What should I do to realise a client-side playlist using java? I wish you could give me more suggest, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While the functionality is not built-in, Wowza does have a module called StreamPublisher to allow you to implement a server-side type of playlist. The source code for the module is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/WowzaMediaSystems/wse-plugin-streampublisher). A scheduled playlist of multiple VOD files is streamed as a live stream, similar to a TV broadcast.